# Implemented a Master Page to my site, and now forms doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, forms, master-pages

I just implemented my website with a Master Page. so it loads the same header and same footer
for every page,
and now my forms doesn't work anymore.
tried to move the `<form>` tag inside the master page and outside and still nothing.

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebSite.master.cs" Inherits="WebSite.WebSite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="titleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="Resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Resources/css/jqModal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Resources/css/boxy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Resources/css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Resources/js/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="Resources/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="Resources/js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="Resources/js/soundmanager.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="Resources/js/JScriptFunctions.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="Resources/js/jquery.boxy.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Resources/js/styled.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" id="aspnetForm" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
        if (!theForm) {
            theForm = document.aspnetForm;
        }
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
            if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
                theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                theForm.submit();
            }
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="animation">
            <div id="ctl00_singleBannerHomePage_pnlFlashContent">
            </div>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                generateBanner(980, 220, 'ctl00_singleBannerHomePage_pnlFlashContent', 'bannersingleBannerHomePage', 'http://www.WebSite.com//Resources//flash/topmenu.swf', '');
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="banner" style="text-align: center;">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="960" height="120"
                id="logo_250x105" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="Resources/flash/banner_960x120.swf">
                <param name="quality" value="high">
                <param name="play" value="true">
                <param name="loop" value="true">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <param name="scale" value="showall">
                <param name="menu" value="true">
                <param name="devicefont" value="false">
                <param name="salign" value="">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Resources/flash/banner_960x120.swf"
                    width="960" height="120">
                    <param name="movie" value="/resources/flash/banner_960x120.swf">
                    <param name="quality" value="high">
                    <param name="play" value="true">
                    <param name="loop" value="true">
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                    <param name="scale" value="showall">
                    <param name="menu" value="true">
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false">
                    <param name="salign" value="">
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="Resources/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
                    </a>
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Main" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="menu_footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="ctl01_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/">
                    Home</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl03_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/">
                    Login</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl05_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/register">
                    Free Register</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl07_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/how">
                    How Does it work</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl15_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/winners">
                    Winners List</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl17_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/myAccount">
                    Members</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl19_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/">
                    Site Map</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl21_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/contact">
                    Contact</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl23_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/terms">
                    Terms & Policy</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a id="ctl25_lnkMenuOption" href="http://www.WebSite.com/about">
                    About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">Beta</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">Beta</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">Beta</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">Beta</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">Beta</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">Beta</a></li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li>
                    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" addthis:url="http://www.facebook.com/pages/WebSite/187442987973985" ></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_tweet" addthis:url="http://www.WebSite.com/" ></a>
                    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style" addthis:url="http://www.WebSite.com/" ></a>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">                     var addthis_config = { "data_track_clickback": true };</script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=danpe"></script>
                    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
                </li>
                <li class="separator">|</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.WebSite.com/" target="_blank">WebSite © 2011</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashAlert" name="flashAlert" data="Resources/flash/AlertPlayer.swf"
        width="1" height="1">
    </object>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#adscaptcha_facebook_like_holder').remove();
            $('#adscaptcha_buttons_holder').remove();
            $('#adscaptcha_r4').remove();
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23547527-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.WebSite.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" MasterPageFile="~/WebSite.Master" Title="" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="titleContent" Runat="Server">
    WebSite!
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ContentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <meta name="AUTHOR" content="WebSite.com"> 
    <meta name="CLASSIFACTION" content="auction, auctions"> 
    <meta name="RATING" content="GENERAL"> 
    <meta name="DISTRIBUTION" content="GLOBAL"> 
    <meta name="REVISIT" content="1 DAYS"> 
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
    <meta property="og:title" content="WebSite! - SecondLife Auctions" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="WebSite" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="hhttp://www.WebSite.com/Resources/images/logo.png" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.WebSite.com/" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1277633739" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.WebSite.com/Resources/images/logo.png" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.WebSite.com/WebSite.ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alertMe(message) {
            var options = $.extend({ title: "Information" }, options || {});
            var dialog = new Boxy("<div><p>" + message + "<a href='#' onclick='Boxy.get(this).hide(); return false'>Close me!</a></p></div>", options);
            allDialogs.push(dialog);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var message = "Impossible Action";
        function clickIE() { if (document.all) { return false; } }
        function clickNS(e) {
            if
        (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
                if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { return false; }
            }
        }
        if (document.layers)
        { document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown = clickNS; }
        else { document.onmouseup = clickNS; document.oncontextmenu = clickIE; }
        document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false")
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #ctl00_singleBannerHomePage_pnlFlashContent
        {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="ContentMain" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server" >
    <div id="content">
        <div class="sign-in-home">
            <div class="login-form-home">
                <% Response.Write(LoginPanel()); %>
                <input type="submit" name="cmdLogin" value="Login" id="cmdLogin" class="red-button" tabindex="3" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-text-home"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-by-home">
        <% Response.Write(SortPanel()); %>
    </div>
    <% Response.Write(Auctions()); %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            startAuctionsServiceHomePage();
        });
    </script>
</asp:content>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page_Load");
    if (Request.Form["cmdLogin"] != null && Request.Form["cmdLogin"] != "")
    {
        Response.Write("cmdLogin");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **Respone.Write("cmdLogin"); doesn't show up**, and it used to show up before i had the Master Page.

Comment: Please show us your master page and a page that uses it.

Comment: What does "Doesn't Work" mean? Are you getting an HTML error code, a blank page, or something else?

Comment: It looks like you posted the output markup from the website.  Or did you actually write the postback scripts that asp generates?  Can you change the code above to be the code that you have in the .master file and not the generated file?

Comment: @mtazva it just doesn't  do anything, just refreshes the page.
@mrK i copy pasted from my .master page it's not the generated file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<input type="submit" name="cmdLogin" value="Login" id="cmdLogin" class="red-button" tabindex="3" runat="server" />
```

to this:

```
<asp:Button id="cmdLogin" Text="Login" CSSClass="red-button" tabindex="3" runat="server" />
```

and then in the .cs file you can access the button by:

```
cmdLogin.Text = "newText";
```

*Edit*

add this to the asp:Button tag

```
OnClick="ClickedFunction"
```

**OR**

add this to the .cs file:

```
protected override void onInit(EventArgs e)
{
    cmdLogin.Click += new EventHandler(cmdLogin_click);
}

void cmdLogin_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code for click here
}
```

Comment: How can i know which button has been clicked if i have more then 1 submit button ?
using if (IsPostBack)
like i used 
if (Request.Form["cmdLogin"] != null && Request.Form["cmdLogin"] != "")
that doesn't work now

Comment: thanks one last question, if i have 1 button, and i use this:
cmdLogin.Name = "cmdLogout";
cmdLogin.Value = "Logout";
cmdLogin.ID = "cmdLogout";
else if (cmdLogin.Value ==  "Logout")
doesn't work...

Comment: it would be better to just add a second button and as the last line in the click you would put cmdLogin.Visible = false; cmdLogout.Visible = true;  Use two buttons and just switch their visibility back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

Even when you are using a master page, you still only get one markup coming out of it.  So look at it this way:

Master Page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST' action='index.aspx'>

<placeholder>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm:

```
<content>
<input type='text' value='hello' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</content>
```

output Markup

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST' action='index.aspx'>

<input type='text' value='hello' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The point is that if you use a form in both, you can expect to have nested forms appear on the final markup if you have forms in both.  This is just an outline of what it can look like.  If you post your pages we can give you more appropriate assistance.

*Edit*

Take advantage of the OOP available in C# - Create a Button object and append it to the page.  You will always have a reference to it that way.  Avoid writing to the response in asp.Net

Comment: Sorry I posted that before you posted your code.  The only difference is that the form in mine is on the master page.

Comment: @mrK yes i changed my form to be on the Master as well, and still nothing.

Comment: I think that your problem might be that you are rewriting javascript that is written by the .Net structure in your page.  The scripts inside the CDATA tag may be overwriting the .Net functions.  Are you working in visual studio?

Comment: Yes visual studio.. And i always had the //<![CDATA[ it's not that...
look at the new .cs file i added

Comment: is there any reason you are using response.write() ?

Comment: @mrK i found the problam ! the generated code submit button ID somehow changes to: ctl00_Main_cmdLogin why is that? and how can i change it ?

Comment: ok so what you need is when you reference the cmdLogin button, instead of looking for cmdLogin you need to look for '<% cmdLogin.ClientID %>'  In order to facilitate having nested controls in .Net, each page's controls get prefixes added on so that they don't have the same name.

Comment: Each control on an ASPX page has two id's,  the ID parameter that identifies the control on the server and the ClientID parameter that identifies the control on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

@Danpe - have you taken a look at the page source that is rendered before you click the cmdLogin button? Have you placed a break point in the page_load to see what the value of Request.Form["cmdLogin"] is?

Unless you are using Framework 4 and static control ID mechanism, the ID/name of the cmdLogin button will not actually be "cmdLogin", but rather a modified name to ensure that ID does not conflict with other controls in the page. This has been standard behavior of ASP.Net since its inception, I believe.

Since cmdLogin is a server-side control, you would actually be better served by adding a button click event handler in the codebehind, rather than trying to manually parse the form parameters. You seem to be fighting with the features that Web Forms provides.

Answer (score 1):

Move your form declaration to the master page, something like:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this block from the master page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
    if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.aspnetForm;
    }
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
            theForm.submit();
        }
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen as a result of the Response.Write("cmdLogin")?  Because all that should happen is that the string "cmdLogin" is included in the result, probably right at the top of the page - try viewing the resulting source, and look right at the top of the page.

Comment: Yes the response.write is just for the debugging when i click the submit it doesn't show up.